# Checking if passwordless ssh authentication is possible without permission for sshd_config

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to check if <strike>authorization</strike> authentication with keys is available without permission to read `ssdh_config` ?

Comment: I just wanted to know if it's possible without password (actually, I was not aware about the DSA keys at the moment of asking this question). Thank for your input anyway :)

Comment: Would you mind rephrasing your question? It's not entirely clear that you weren't asking about RSA at all. I'd completely remove that reference.  I can do it if you like. LMK.

Comment: Sure thing. Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the server is running and reachable:

```
ssh -vvv user@host
```

results in such lines:

```
Authentications that can continue: publickey
Next authentication method: publickey
```

**Edit 1**

Or limit it to the relevant output:

```
ssh -vvv user@host 2>&1 | grep "Next authentication method:"
```

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such line. Just:
debug1: Host '***' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/wiktor/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password

Comment: Did you tried with `-vvv`? it is better to update this kind of information in the question, so it is easier to read and easier to find

Comment: @RSFalcon7: yes, I have. I think this option is just off on this server. I only get info about password authentication.

Answer (score 8):

You can connect to the server allowing only public keys (and exiting immediately) with this command:

```
user@box ~ $ ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no  -o BatchMode=yes HOSTNAME exit &>/dev/null
user@box ~ $ test $? = 0 && echo can connect || echo cannot connect
can connect
user@box ~ $
```

After the main command, you can check the result code to see if you can connect without password or not.

Comment: This does not work if a password is required. Will say "cannot connect" despite being able to connect.